# Show reciprocal rule for total derivatives $D(\frac{1}{f})(x) = -\frac{1}{f^2(x)} Df(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. Show $$D(\frac{1}{f})(x) = -\frac{1}{f^2(x)} Df(x)$$ for all $x \in \Omega$ with $f(x) \neq 0$.

We defined the total derivative as $(V,p)$ and $(W,q)$ finite dimensional vector spaces equipped with the norms p and q, $\Omega \subseteq V$ an open set, $f:\Omega \to W$, $x^* \in \Omega$. $f$ is totally differentiable if there exists a linear map $L:V \to W$ such that $$\lim_{x \to x^*}\frac{f(x) - f(x^*) - L(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)} = 0$$ and the linear map $L = Df(x^*)$ is called the differential of $f$ in $x^*$.

We didn't cover the quotient rule for total derivatives yet but I know the chain rule for total derivatives. I don't know how to apply it to the problem, or even apply the definition to the left side of the equation... From the definition it would have to be $\lim_{x \to x*}\frac{f(x) - f(x^*) - D(\frac1f)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}$ but this makes no sense, I cannot continue from that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You aren't quite stating the definition correctly;  the total derivative is the linear function $L$ such that that limit is $0$.

Comment: you are right, I changed it

Comment: From the definition would it not be $\lim_{x \to x*}\frac{f^{-1}(x) - f^{-1}(x^*) - D(\frac1f)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}$?

Comment: @1950RobertLewis I don't exactly know either, I was confused because in the last part of the definition it states that $Df(x)$ is equal to only the linear term in the numerator.

Comment: I think it means $Df$ for *any* function $f$, so for $f^{-1}$ it would be $Df^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$R(x, x^\ast) = R(x^\ast, x) = \dfrac{1}{f(x)f(x^\ast)} \tag{1}$

and then look at the expression $(f(x^\ast))^{-1} - (f(x))^{-1}$; we have

$\begin{aligned}(f(x^\ast))^{-1} - (f(x))^{-1}&=\dfrac1{f(x^\ast)} - \dfrac{1}{f(x)}\\&=\dfrac{f(x) - f(x^\ast)}{f(x^\ast)f(x)}\\&= R(x, x^\ast)(f(x) - f(x^\ast));\quad (2)\end{aligned}$

noting that

$$\lim_{x \to x^\ast} R(x, x^\ast)  = \dfrac1{(f(x^\ast))^2}  \tag{3}$$

we may use the existence of $Df(x^\ast)$, i.e. that

$$\lim_{x \to x^*}\dfrac{f(x) - f(x^\ast) - Df(x^\ast)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)} = 0 \tag{4}$$

to compute

$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x \to x^*}\dfrac{(f(x))^{-1} - (f(x^\ast))^{-1} + R(x^\ast, x)Df(x^\ast)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}&= \lim_{x \to x^*}\dfrac{R(x^\ast, x)(f(x^\ast) - f(x)) + R(x^\ast, x)Df(x^\ast)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}\\&= \lim_{x \to x^*}-R(x^\ast, x)\dfrac{(f(x) - f(x^\ast)) - Df(x^\ast)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}\\&=\lim_{x \to x^*}-R(x^\ast, x) \lim_{x \to x^*}\dfrac{(f(x) - f(x^\ast)) - Df(x^\ast)(x - x^*)}{p(x - x^*)}\\&=-\dfrac{1}{(f(x^\ast))^2} \times 0 = 0,\quad (5)\end{aligned}$

establishing that

$D(\dfrac{1}{f})(x^\ast) = -R(x^\ast, x^\ast)Df(x^\ast) = -\dfrac{1}{(f(x^\ast))^2} Df(x^\ast). \tag{6}$

***QED.***

***Note Added in Edit:***  There's another way to see this, if one has at their disposal the *Leibniz Product Rule* for derivatives, which says that

$D(fg) = gDf + fDg. \tag{7}$

In the language of ordinary vector calculus, (7) translates to

$\nabla(fg) = f\nabla g + g\nabla f, \tag{8}$

easily verified by simply noting

$\dfrac{\partial (fg)}{\partial x} = f\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} + g\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \tag{9}$

for any coordinate variable $x$.  (7) may also be proved under the present, more abstract definition of derivative given by, e.g., (4).  In any event, noting that

$f(x)f^{-1}(x) = 1, \tag{10}$

we have *via* (7)

$0 = D(1) = D(f(x)f^{-1}(x)) = f^{-1}(x)Df(x) + f(x)Df^{-1}(x), \tag{11}$

which, since $f(x) \ne 0$, may be readily solved for $Df^{-1}(x)$:

$Df^{-1}(x) = -f^{-2}(x)Df(x); \tag{12}$

again I say, ***QED.***

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thak you for your very detailed answer, I will go with your first solution although the second surely is more elegant if you are allowed to use the product rule!

Comment: @sj134:  Hey, glad to help out.  And yeah, I like the second way better.  And thanks for the "acceptance".

Comment: Isn't the operator candidate for the differential supposed to be constant when proving the statement by definition?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $g=1/f$, then
$$
g(x)-g(x^*)+g(x^*)^2\cdot L(x-x^*)$$ is $$-g(x)g(x^*)\,(f(x)-f(x^*)-L(x-x^*))-h(x)\,L(x-x^*)$$
where
$$
h(x)=g(x^*)(g(x)-g(x^*))\to0.
$$
Thus,
$$
Dg(x^*)=-g(x^*)^2\cdot L.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also do as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to x}\frac{\left|\frac1{f(x)}-\frac1{f(c)}-\left(-\frac1{f(c)^2}\right)Df(c)(x-c)\right|}{\|x-c\|}&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\left|\frac{f(c)-f(x)}{f(x)f(c)}+\frac1{f(c)^2}Df(c)(x-c)\right|}{\|x-c\|}\\&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\left|-\frac{f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)(x-c)}{f(x)f(c)}-\frac1{f(x)f(c)}Df(c)(x-c)+\frac1{f(c)^2}Df(c)(x-c)\right|}{\|x-c\|}\\&\le\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\left|-\frac{f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)}{f(x)f(c)}\right|}{\|x-c\|}+\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\left|\frac1{f(c)^2}Df(c)(x-c)-\frac1{f(x)f(c)}Df(c)(x-c)\right|}{\|x-c\|}\\&=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{|f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)(x-c)|}{\|x-c\|}\frac1{|f(x)f(c)|}+\lim_{x\to c}\frac{|Df(x-c)|}{\|x-c\|}\left|\frac1{f(c)^2}-\frac1{f(x)f(c)}\right|\\&\le\lim_{x\to c}\frac{|f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)(x-c)|}{\|x-c\|}\frac1{|f(x)f(c)|}+\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\|Df \|_o\|x-c\|}{\|x-c\|}\left|\frac1{f(c)^2}-\frac1{f(x)f(c)}\right|\\&= \lim_{x\to c}\color{blue}{\frac{|f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)(x-c)|}{\|x-c\|}}\frac1{|f(x)f(c)|}+\lim_{x\to c}\|Df\|_o\color{blue}{\left|\frac1{f(c)^2}-\frac1{f(x)f(c)}\right|}\\&=0.\end{aligned}$$

Now, squeeze.

Note: $\|\cdot\|_o$ denotes the [operatornorm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) and the blue expressions tend to $0$.